# Is there an accepted definition for "P for trend" or "P-trend"

Tags: p-value, definition, test-for-trend

So is "P for trend" the same in principle as a common-or-garden P-value, but in a specific application i.e. odds ratios?

And can P-value, P for trend, and P-trend be regarded as interchangeable conceptually, terminologically, and in terms of statistical significance (at least)?

A pointer to an appropriate and citeable reference would be most useful, particularly if it states any differences or confirms sameness.

*Edit responding to whuber's moderation*

@whuber - thanks, but wouldn't an exact duplicate at least mention the topic of my question. I can see no mention of 'trend' or 'P for trend' on that page you provided. If on the other hand you know that P for trend is the same thing, then is there a citeable reference you can provide? Just to be clearer it is the use of the word 'trend' that confuses me, not the use of letter 'P'.

*Another edit responding to whuber's moderation*

Sorry if my question was not well formed. In attempting to provide my own answer  in the hope of a confirmation, I think that the word 'trend' when talking about P-trend (e.g. for a reported result in the literature) sets the context as a P-value test for linear trend in odds ratio in logistic regression, against a categorical predictor variable. If that is correct, then this is described in standard texts as 'test for trend', in which case my copy of Kirkwood & Sterne provides a citeable reference.
Hopefully this addresses whuber's concerns. Whilst the correct interpretation of P-value is very important, I was missing the context of logistic regression.

Comment: I might add I have seen P for trend used where significance is 'weak' and where '...P for trend <0.0005..', so I'm not sure that helps me.

Comment: @whuber - thanks, but wouldn't an exact duplicate at least mention the topic of my question. I can see no mention of 'trend' or 'P for trend' on that page you provided. If on the other hand you know that P for trend is the same thing, then is there a citeable reference you can provide?  

Just to be clearer it is the use of the word 'trend' that confuses me, not the use of letter 'P'.

Comment: One moderation principle I apply is to consider what kinds of questions might additionally be allowed if one particular variation of an existing question were considered different. In this case, when I contemplate the infinity of possible questions of the form "what does 'p for odds ratio' mean," "what does 'p for a quadratic term mean'," "what does p for 'intercept' mean," I find it easy to conclude that making all these into separate questions would be pointless. The duplicate answers the entire set of questions by explaining what a p-value means for a general statistical procedure.

Comment: This Q&A helped with my second edit above
http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/56730-Test-for-linear-trend-in-odds-ratio-in-linear-regression

Comment: ...as did this http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/183518/calculate-p-trends